# How to add commas without rounding off the decimal points in angular 4 pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi how to add commas without rounding off the decimal points?

example:

```
const data = 1000.789343;
const data = 1000.786;
```

output should be

```
1,000.789343
1,000.786
```

I tried some solutions:

```
new DecimalPipe(data, '2.')
```

But none of it worked. It will keep rounding off the decimal points. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `data.ToLocaleString()` if that doesn't work, then you need to specify it as your country doesn't use that format

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see updated question.

Comment: @rj.learn do you want to use Intl format

Comment: sorry `data.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumSignificantDigits : 21})` i didn't pay attention to the longer decimals

Answer (score 2):

Try Usng Decimal pipe of angular like: `{{ yourData | number:'.3-3'}}` after specifiying values after ".". It will not round off values

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}.
```

> minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the
>   decimal point. Default is 1. minFractionDigits: The minimum number of
>   digits after the decimal point. Default is 0. maxFractionDigits: The
>   maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

Please visit angular documentation "[Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)"

Comment: I **think** there's a correct answer hiding in there. You'd just give a really big value (not 3, as in your example) for `maxFractionDigits`, right?

Comment: Yes, It was just an example.. you can modify it accordingly

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to provide an example that worked with the OP's sample values?

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use custom code for the same.

```
var test = 24682476824.7868756;
var formatedval  = test.toString().split('.')[0].split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g).join(",") + '.' + test.toString().split('.')[1];
console.log(formatedval)
```

Output: 24,682,476,824.786877

Comment: How does this relate to an Angular 4 pipe?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We will have to create custom pipe for the same

Comment: That seems to be missing from the answer. Also, probably better to just use the predefined one.

Comment: Not sure whether angular has predefined pipe for the functionality. In latest release angular has removed all predefined pipes if I am not wrong

Comment: DecimalPipe, [as answered by Danish Arora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789645/157247), is listed in the current docs: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ohh Thats great

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'keepDecimals'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, keepDecimals: boolean): string {
    const options = keepDecimals ? {maximumSignificantDigits : 21} : {};
    return value.toLocaleString(undefined, options);
  }
}

<p>{{1000.789343 | keepDecimals: true}}</p>
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with DecimalPipe ([Danish Arora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789645/157247))?

Comment: I just realized how DecimalPipe works. This could be an alternative, without specifying max-min